# Variable assignment in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have a question about variable assignment in Elixir. In Erlang, this would raise a `no match of right hand side value`:

```
X = 4.
X = 2.
```

However, it seems perfectly fine in Elixir to assign a value to a variable more than once. I am confused how pattern matching works in Elixir. How does Elixir differentiate between pattern matching and variable assignment? From what I understand, in Erlang, `X` is an unbound variable so it can be matched with anything, right? But once it is bound, pattern matching only works if it is the same value as `X`. So does Elixir not share the same concept of unbound variables as Erlang?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Elixir doesn't follow the same concept as Erlang in this regard. Elixir tries to be more accessible for developers less familiar with functional programming, especially Ruby developers. According to [Pattern matching](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html) documentation you have to pin variable:

```
iex(1)> x=4
4
iex(2)> ^x=2
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 2
```

Also, note that variables have to start with a lower case in Elixir.

Comment: The http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/01/comparing-elixir-and-erlang-variables/ article is a great explanation of the reasoning behind this behaviour.

Comment: How is this in explanation instead of a workaround ? Taking Erlang as a start I find this extremely confusing and non-logical. There is no matching in Elixir, they call it rebinding. The link from @michalmuskala is useful, although it also does not explain this in a way that satisfies me to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to actually answer the question, using knowledge from the link. Elixir does not do matching with the = operator , it does something called rebinding. The code example shows how Elixir can be made to behave like Erlang, which is completely illogical to me as a total new user of the language. I hope to revisit this answer in the future to write something better :).

So Elixir uses pattern matchin when the variable is preceded with a ^ instead of rebinding. My question is : in a big piece of code how those one keep track of first use and use this notation?
It would be great if anyone can provide a good answer to that :).